# Regex to identify the text including square brackets

Tags: python, regex

I have a sample string as - x = "something [TextA][TextB]",  with following re command-

```
re.search('\[(.*)\]',x).groups()
```

I was able to achieve outcome as - "[TextA][TextB]" but I am looking for outcome as list as - ["[TextA]","[TextB]"]

Comment: Use `\[([^\]]*)\]`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I was able to achieve outcome as - "[TextA][TextB]"

Because `.*` is [greedy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2301285/what-do-lazy-and-greedy-mean-in-the-context-of-regular-expressions), the first match skips past the first `]` enclosing `TextA` and continues to the second one enclosing `TextB`.

Use `.*?` for a non-greedy match. You don't strictly need this tool; you can instead match "any number of characters that are not `]`", like `[^\]]*`. But I think `.*?` is a lot easier, and generalizes better.

> but I am looking for outcome as list

If you need to get a specific number of matches, then you can explicitly specify each in your regex, with the appropriate capture for each. If you need any number of matches, use `findall` rather than `search`:

```
>>> re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', 'foo[bar][baz]')
['bar', 'baz']
```